# Excel UDF within UDF giving #VALUE error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Firstly, thanks to nixda for the hashing code!

I am kind of new to VBA. I am trying to create a function that takes an email address and obfuscates the username portion so a report containing the obfuscated email address can be distributed.

I've put the following in a VBA module:

```
Private Function EncodeBase64(ByVal sTextToHash As String)

Dim objXML As Object
Dim objNode As Object

Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
EncodeBase64 = objNode.Text

Set objNode = Nothing
Set objXML = Nothing

End Function

Public Function BASE64SHA1(ByVal sTextToHash As String)

Dim asc As Object
Dim enc As Object
Dim TextToHash() As Byte
Dim SharedSecretKey() As Byte
Dim bytes() As Byte
Const cutoff As Integer = 5

Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")

TextToHash = asc.GetBytes_4(sTextToHash)
SharedSecretKey = asc.GetBytes_4(sTextToHash)
enc.Key = SharedSecretKey

bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
BASE64SHA1 = EncodeBase64(bytes)
BASE64SHA1 = Left(BASE64SHA1, cutoff)

Set asc = Nothing
Set enc = Nothing

End Function
```

And I can obfuscate an email address fine if I call the function in the workbook:

```
=BASE64SHA1(LEFT(A1,FIND("@",A1)-1))&"@"&MID(A1,FIND("@",A1)+1,999)
```

So if I pass this function I get an email address with a hashed username. Great!

But I'd like to be able to type:

```
=OBFUSCATEEMAIL(A1)
```

in the worksheet

So I opened up the worksheet's VBA module and so far I have:

```
Public Function ObfuscateEmail(ByVal email As String)

    Dim username As String
    Dim domain As String

    username = Left(email, InStr(email, "@") - 1)
    domain = Right(email, Len(email) - InStr(email, "@"))

    ObfuscateEmail = BASE64SHA1(username) & "@" & domain

End Function
```

When I try calling this new function, I get a #VALUE error!

The call to BASE64SHA1 is causing the issue, but:

a) I know BASE64SHA1 is working when called from the worksheet, and

b) I ObfuscateEmail works fine until I add the call to BASE64SHA1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code:

```
objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
```

uses a variable that is neither **Dim**'ed nor has been assigned a value.

Comment: So why would that line be causing zero issues when called from the workbook (via BASE64SHA1) but cause problems when called from within the module?

Comment: My bad, had screwed up the header of EncodeBase64 somewhere along the road, which should be `Private Function EncodeBase64(ByRef arrData() As Byte) As String`. This fixes the problem you've pointed out.. thanks!

Comment: @DavidVernon Good Job with the debug!